# @reboot with crontab, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mount, cron

I have an .sh file located at '/home/pi/startup.sh' which I want to have running soon after bootup.
I have my `crontab` with the following information.

```
# m h dom mon dow user        command
17 *        * * *        root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6        * * *        root        test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6        * * 7        root        test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6        1 * *        root        test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
0  0        * * *   root        reboot        
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /home/pi/startup.sh > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
#
```

And the .sh is

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //◘◘◘.◘◘◘.◘◘◘.◘/Public /home/pi/wdmycloud
#
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //◘◘◘.◘◘◘.◘◘◘.◘/Jared /home/pi/Jared
#
sleep 10
feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B black -F -Z -z -r /home/pi/wdmycloud/SkyNetPhotos/
```

What am I doing wrong? The script, should start a picture slide show using picture from the drives. But nothing happened, even hours of letting it sit.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` Nobody knows because you're not telling us what the problem is. What does not work as expected?

Comment: The script isn't running when system reboots.

Comment: How do you know the script isn't running?

Comment: The script shown is to mount 2 disks from a wireless server that's on the network, and start a slideshow from a folder found on one of the drives.

Comment: How do you know the script is not running?  You need to edit your question and include all relevant detail.

Comment: Details have been added

Comment: Does your sudo require a password?  Look in /var/log/syslog to see if the reason for script failure is given.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider putting your `mount` actions in `/etc/fstab` instead of an `@reboot` facility in your `crontab`.

Beyond that, some potential issues:

1. Your `mount` commands look suspect. Try something like:

```
sudo mount //192.168.1.246/whatever /home/pi/somedir -o username=yours,rw,vers=1.0
```

Refer to `man mount` for details on the options. And note in particular:

```
Mount options for cifs
       See the options section of the mount.cifs(8) man page (cifs-utils package must be installed).
```

2. You've cleverly added the `stderr` redirect, but you haven't shared with us what you found when you looked in your `/home/pi/cronjoblog` file... do you mind doing that?
3. I'm guessing here, but your shell script may need either a shebang as the first line, or change your `crontab` line to make it clear you want it to run under the `bash` shell:

```
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /bin/bash /home/pi/startup.sh > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

4. And if none of that works, try using complete path specs in your .sh script; for example:

instead of: `sudo mount ...` , use `/usr/bin/sudo /bin/mount ...`

etc.

Comment: 1. I've added the line suggested to the fstab and yet nothing happened

Comment: 2. I've been trying to get this process to spit out a log to the conjoblog, but it still remains empty.

Comment: 2. I don't know what you mean by "shebang" I added it to the begging before "sudo mount" and it just tells me "shebang:not found.  Mount error (16).

Comment: @user46629: Please use a search engine. If you Google `shebang`, you'll get answers like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: I feel really stupid now. And also mind blown about the concept of a shebang.

Comment: @user46629: Not stupid, you simply have some learning to do. Read, experiment, then ask questions... you'll own this place eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you run your .sh script manually before putting it through the cronjob. You should also check the permissions for the file. I would just allow all users to execute the file :

`sudo chmod a+x /home/pi/startup.sh`

For the `crontab` file i think you can do it in this way :

```
@reboot sleep 10 && /home/pi/startup.sh
```

Comment: Script runs perfectly after system has booted up and I execute it via terminal

Comment: Good. Is the permission correctly set ? Try running the cronjob the way I posted.

Comment: I did the "sudo chmod a+x /home/pi/startup.sh" and nothing happened. I applied the changes to the crontab that you suggested and after 2mins of waiting, nothing.